# plugging open gl es extensions into app

Tags: android, opengl-es, sony-xperia

I'm dealing with some compatibility issues on my Xperia Play phone while trying to run my game, and because of that I must find all references to OpenGL ES extensions that are used
within my app. This leads us to my question: Are there ways to use extensions other than via eglGetProcAddress() function?

Best regards,
Buyuk.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  The normal way to use extensions is to call them directly by name, which will contain one of these strings:

```
OES, ARB, IMG, PVR, EXT, AMD, VIV or NV
```

The names are defined in these header files:

```
#include <EGL/eglext.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
```

The names returned from a query are different.  They typically look like this:

GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
 GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
 GL_AMD_performance_monitor
 GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
 GL_AMD_tiled_rendering
 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
 GL_EXT_bgra
 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
 GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
 GL_OES_depth_texture
 GL_OES_depth24
 GL_OES_EGL_image
 GL_OES_EGL_image_external
 GL_OES_element_index_uint
 GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
 GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
 GL_OES_get_program_binary
 GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
 GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
 GL_OES_standard_derivatives
 GL_OES_texture_3D
 GL_OES_texture_float
 GL_OES_texture_half_float
 GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
 GL_OES_texture_npot
 GL_OES_vertex_half_float
 GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
 GL_NV_fence

Answer (score 0):

No, not all extensions define new api calls, so eglGetProcAddress is not used for all of them. 
The good example is http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt - see there are new tokens (enums) here, but no new functions.

However compiling without *gl*ext.h headers, tracing out eglGetProcAddress and "#extension"  strings in ESSL will give you at least some info on used non-core functionalities.